# How to reset highlight ColorIndex property to no highlight in word app

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am adding a text in **header** of a word document with bookmark.

Then am highlighting the bookmark's text.

**But if after that I enter or type some another text that also get highlights.**

My Code is:

```
Word.Document currDocument = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
Word.Selection currentSelection = WordApp.Selection;
if(currentSelection.HeaderFooter.IsHeader)
{
    Word.Range selectionRange = currentSelection.Range;

    selectionRange.Text ="abc";

    currentDocument.Bookmarks.Add("bookmark", selectionRange);
    currentDocument.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Select();

    WordApp.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;

    **//from here I want to set highlight as off**
}
```

I want to highlight only bookmark part not after that.

Comment: Word macro recorder gives me `wdNoHighlight`. Confirmed in one of my interop apps to be `Word.WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cindy correctly mentions, working with Selection should be avoided wherever possible.
This being said, you need to apply `wdNoHighLight` to a non-empty range in order to take effect.
So, beginning with your last line, the following code does this. Adapt to your needs as you see fit:

```
WordApp.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;
WordApp.Selection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
WordApp.Selection.MoveRight(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1, Extend: true);
WordApp.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight;
WordApp.Selection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
WordApp.Selection.TypeText("YaddaYadda");
```

You should see "YaddaYadda" without highlight.

A little extra: double dots (dot-Selection-dot) usually cause trouble when working with COM objects. Try to use substitute variables instead. Also make sure to use

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
```

And also release all other of your Word references before code end.

Edit: Alternative without Selection. The easiest way is to simply use replace on the non-highlighted text. To simplify things, I accessed the primary header of the first page.

```
var section = currDocument.Sections.First;
var header = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
var hRange = header.Range.FormattedText;
var highlightedText = "abc";
var normalText = " Yadda yadda";

//insert highlighted text and bookmark
hRange.Text = highlightedText;
currDocument.Bookmarks.Add("bookmark", hRange);
hRange.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;

//insert normal text, turn off highlighting
hRange.InsertAfter(normalText);
var find = hRange.Find;
find.ClearFormatting();
find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
find.Text = normalText;
find.Replacement.Text = normalText;
find.Replacement.Highlight = (int) Word.WdColorIndex.wdNoHighlight;
find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(find);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(hRange);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(header);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(section);
```

Comment: Note: Of course you could also simply turn this around: first fill your header(s) with the text you want in it and set your bookmark without setting the highlight at this point, then do a quick replace of the text you wish to highlight and replace it with your favourite highlight colour set...

Answer (score 2):

Working with a `Selection` object is always tricky and should be avoided if possible. There are times when it helps, but for the majority of cases working with `Range` objects is more reliable. `Selection` pretty much mirrors how the user has to work. If, as a user, you type something, select it, apply highlighting, then type some more you see exactly the behavior described. As a user you'd then need to select what you've typed and remove the highlighting - even if it's only one or two characters. From that point on, the highlighting is gone. This is painful both as a user, or trying to mimic it in code.

Consider the following variation on the code in the question. After the bookmark has been inserted a second `Range` object is set to the original `Range` using the `Duplicate` property. (`Duplicate` is important because otherwise the two `Range` objects would be identical - changing one would also change the other.)

This second `Range` object is moved to a position beyond the original `Range`. Now the two can be handled differently. Unlike a `Selection` code can work with many `Ranges`.

```
Word.Document currDocument = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
Word.Selection currentSelection = WordApp.Selection;
if(currentSelection.HeaderFooter.IsHeader)
{
  Word.Range selectionRange = currentSelection.Range;
  selectionRange.Text ="abc";
  currentDocument.Bookmarks.Add("bookmark", selectionRange);
  //currentDocument.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Select();
  Word.Range rngAfterBookmark = selectionRange.Duplicate;
  //go to the end of the bookmarked range
  rngAfterBookmark.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
  //make sure the two ranges are no longer adjacent
  rngAfterBookmark.Text = " ";
  rngAfterBookmark.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
  selectionRange.HighlightColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;
}
```

Note: Usually I would not even work with `Selection` in a Header or Footer, but with the Header or Footer's `Range`. I didn't change this because I don't know the logic of the code up until this point.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.It helps me in solving the problem. Can I get a little example of adding bookmark with header footer range as per your way, so that I can replace **Selection**  process from my code for enhancement

Comment: @AmarMalik Could you please post this as a new question, with the usual attention to [mcve]? It's outside the parameters of the original question... But there are lots of code examples for working with the Header/Footer "out there".